# How to add type Object of numbers in JAVA

Tags: java

```
Object a = 1;// or "1"
Object b = 2;// or "2"
```

What should i do to get a + b = 3?
Using Integer.parseInt may not work for my function, since I am doing a recursion based on them.

Basically, I am writing a static method for Fibonacci number by suing binary tree.

```
myNode = new TreeNode(fibTreeHelper(n-1).myItem +  fibTreeHelper(n-2).myItem,
                      fibTreeHelper(n-1), fibTreeHelper(n-2));
```

Constructor of TreeNode is TreeNode(myItem, leftBranch, rightBranch)
myItem is an Object. I keep calling my helper function until n = 0 or 1, so I have the first two number in the Fibonacci sequence.

What shoold I do?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand, but you can use the Integer, Long, Short, etc class to keep numbers in an Object type, and auto-unboxing/auto-boxing will treat them as normal numbers. For example, Integer a = 1, b = 2, c; c = a + b; System.out.println(c); Will print 3.

Comment: Another possibility would be to change the fibTreeHelper to take an 'int' as argument, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why are you suing a binary tree? Whatever did it do to you that you should sue it?

Comment: Why should `myItem` be an `Object`?  Using an `Integer` or `Long` would be far better.

Comment: I am taking JAVA, and now we are on the topic of TREE. Its an assignment, requiring me to generate Fibonacci numbers and other stuff by using binary tree. MyItem is required to be an Object, TAs like generic, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the data type's class counterpart. There's Integer, Short, Long, etc classes that hold on to the number and can be treated as regular numbers as well thanks to auto (un)boxing. When you type

```
Integer a = 5;
```

The compiler will automatically expand it

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
```

And the same goes for the other way around. So to answer your question,

```
Integer a = 1, b = 2, c;
c = a + b; //Now holds Integer of 3
```

And then when receive it as an Object, you can cast it back to an Integer and then use it as necessary.

```
Integer a = (Integer) aObj;
```